# Next.js - export index.html

Tags: next.js

I would like to host my React Project on **Amazon S3**.

I am developing it with `Next.js`.

the folder tree is like below this.

```
pages
 |- auth
 |    |- index.tsx
 |- (...)
 |- index.tsx
```

and I did

```
next build && next export
```

After building and exporting, I expected it

```
out
 |- _next
 |- auth
 |    |- index.html /* I want another index.html */
 |- (...)
 |- index.html
 |- static
```

but I got it,

```
 |- _next
 |- auth.html /*I need /auth/index.html*/
 |- (...)
 |- index.html
 |- static
```

How could I achieve it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap#adding-a-trailing-slash

Just add `exportTrailingSlash: true` to `next.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

Comment: Note: the `exportTrailingSlash` option has been renamed to `trailingSlash`.

Comment: `trailingSlash: true,` did what I wanted, it created the folder structure where `/about` becomes `/about/index.html` -- I just didn't believe it

Comment: How can a webserver like nginx do anything without any `.html` exported ? What is this NextJS black magic ?

Answer (score 5):

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: async function (defaultPathMap) {
    return {
      '/auth/index.html': { page: '/auth' },
    };
  }
}
```